# Variáveis com caracteres especiais

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Olá,

Estou a tentar criar uma classe do gênero:

```
[DataContract, Serializable]
public class XMLCM5050 : XmlApi
{
    [DataMember]
    public string $name{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string $age{ get; set; }
}
```

Sei que não é possível adicionar  o simbolo "$" ao nome das variáveis. Existe alguma forma de conseguir ter esse simbolo nas variáveis quando esta for serializada?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: E porque quer isto?

Answer (score 4):

Tente informar o *alias* via declaração da propriedade `Name` de `DataMember`:

```
[DataContract, Serializable]
public class XMLCM5050 : XmlApi
{
    [DataMember(Name="$name")]
    public string name{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="$age")]
    public string age{ get; set; }
}
```